# Запись в бд формат datetime

Tags: python, oracle

Данные: 11.10.2019 00:00:00 - row[0]

```
for row in spamreader:
statement = "INSERT INTO table(DT, test1, test2) values (TO_DATE(:2, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), :3, :4)"
    cur.execute(statement, (row[0], row[1], row[2]))
    con.commit()
```

Ошибка: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: А правильно, что параметры в запросе начинаются с `:2`, а не, например, с `:1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Секунды забыли. 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'